# Change format of hyperref generated PDF bookmarks

Tags: hyperref, numbering, bookmarks

In a generic way, how can I change the format of bookmarks generated automatically by `hyperref` (or `bookmark`)?

By generic, I mean the ability the customize the bookmark format for `part`, `chapter`, `section`, etc. without having to modify the document TeX.  Ideally it will be contained in a class wrapper.

Bookmark format ideas:

- Unnumbered parts, numbered chapters, unnumbered sections/subsections (but they all are numbered - `not@star`).
- Part format: "Part <#>: " or ", Part <#>"
- Move number to after the title

MWE:

```
\document{scrbook}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}
\begin{document}
\part{Test Part}
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}
\part{Test Part}
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}
\end{document}
```

Here's the index output (evince) marked up with what I would like to do.  Perhaps rewriting a `bookmark`/`hyperref` command would do?

[image: sample output]

Comment: Do you want this change to be global, or just for `\part`s and `\chapter`s?

Comment: Updated question to (hopefully) clarify.  Looking for a global solution that is configurable for each heading type.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following provides the functionality to swap titles and numbers in the bookmarks:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}% http://ctan.org/pkg/KOMA-script
% \usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}% http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox

\makeatletter
\let\store@Hy@writebookmark\Hy@writebookmark
% Argument patching inside a macro: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113147/5764
\catcode`\#=12
% Swap num/title in bookmarks
\newcommand{\reversetitlenumswap}{%
  % \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
  \patchcmd{\Hy@writebookmark}{#2}{\BKM@reversetitle}{}{}%
  \patchcmd{\Hy@writebookmark}{\bookmark}{\let\numberline\@gobble\edef\BKM@reversetitle{#2\ #1}\bookmark}{}{}%
}
\catcode`\#=6
\newcommand{\reverttitlenumswap}{\let\Hy@writebookmark\store@Hy@writebookmark}% Revert num/title swap in bookmarks
% Section-specific swapping of num/title in bookmarks
\newcommand{\parttitlenumswap}{\renewcommand{\addparttocentry}[2]{{\reversetitlenumswap\addtocentrydefault{part}{##1}{##2}}}}
\newcommand{\chaptertitlenumswap}{\renewcommand{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{{\reversetitlenumswap\addtocentrydefault{chapter}{##1}{##2}}}}
\newcommand{\sectiontitlenumswap}{\renewcommand{\addsectiontocentry}[2]{{\reversetitlenumswap\addtocentrydefault{section}{##1}{##2}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\parttitlenumswap% Swap \part num/title in bookmarks
\sectiontitlenumswap% Swap \section num/title in bookmarks

\part{Test Part}
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}

\part{Test Part}
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}

\end{document}
```

The above MWE provides `\reversetitlenum` that acts as a switch. After calling this macro, all subsequent sectional units will have a swapped number/title in the bookmarks. `\reverttitlenum` is a switch that reverts back to the default presentation.

Separate macros for each sectional unit (`\part`, `\chapter` and `\section`, although other can also be defined as needed) is also provided to selectively activate the swapping of bookmark constructions.

The main approach to this solution is to hack into `\Hy@writebookmark` - the macro that is finally called to construct the bookmark (from [`bookmark.dtx`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/bookmark.dtx)):

```
\def\Hy@writebookmark#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifnum#4>\BKM@depth\relax
  \else
    \def\BKM@type{#5}%
    \ifx\BKM@type\Hy@bookmarkstype
      \begingroup
        \ifBKM@numbered
          \let\numberline\Hy@numberline
          \let\booknumberline\Hy@numberline
          \let\partnumberline\Hy@numberline
          \let\chapternumberline\Hy@numberline
        \else
          \let\numberline\@gobble
          \let\booknumberline\@gobble
          \let\partnumberline\@gobble
          \let\chapternumberline\@gobble
        \fi
        \bookmark[level=#4,dest={#3}]{#2}%
      \endgroup
    \fi
  \fi
}
```

It takes 5 arguments of which the first 2 are the most important from a visual/end user perspective. `#1` contains the sectional unit number `<num>` (although it is never used), while `#2` contains a ToC-like entry of the form `\protect\numberline{<num>}<title>`. The default is to only use `#2`. The suggested patch in `\reversetitlenumswap` uses both, printing it as `#2\ #1` while also temporarily deactivating the macro `\numberline`. The patch is inserted just above the `\bookmark` entry, while also updating the use of only `#2` (resulting in two separate patches).

It is not necessary to load [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref). [`bookmark`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark) loads `hyperref` and uses some of its code. See [Which package should I load first: `hyperref` or `bookmark`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113006/5764)