# Patching arguments inside a macro

Tags: macros, etoolbox

Consider the following example of a patch using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) and a dummy macro `\abc`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\newcommand{\abc}[2]{#1\ #2}% Magic macro
\begin{document}
\abc{A}{B}

% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\abc}{#1}{#2}{}{}%
\abc{A}{B}
\end{document}
```

If I want to maintain good programming practice, I'm encouraged to put `\patchcmd` in the document preamble (separating structure from content) and only trigger it with a different macro, say `\patchabc`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\newcommand{\abc}[2]{#1\ #2}% Magic macro
\newcommand{\patchabc}{%
  % \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
  \patchcmd{\abc}{#1}{#2}{}{}%
}
\begin{document}
\abc{A}{B}

\patchabc% Patch \abc
\abc{A}{B}
\end{document}
```

However, the above does not work since `#1` and `#2` inside `\patchabc` is assumed to reference its arguments while `\patchabc` has none. How can I write a macro that acts like a switch (and is cleaner in terms of the programming) that patches another macro's use of its own arguments?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you add `\tracingpatches` to the preamble you find the answer in the `log`:

```
[debug] tracing \patchcmd on input line 14
[debug] analyzing '\abc'
[debug] ++ control sequence is defined
[debug] ++ control sequence is a macro
[debug] -- nested patching command and parameters in patch
[debug] -> the patching command seems to be nested in the
[debug]    argument to some other command
[debug] -> the patch text seems to contain # characters
[debug] -> either avoid nesting or use # characters with
[debug]    category code 12 in the patch text
[debug] -> simply doubling the # characters will not work
```

And indeed, changing the catcode of `#` to `12` is working:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\tracingpatches
\newcommand{\abc}[2]{#1\ #2}% Magic macro
\catcode`\#=12
\newcommand{\patchabc}{%
  % \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
  \patchcmd{\abc}{#1}{#2}{}{}%
}
\catcode`\#=6
\begin{document}
\abc{A}{B}

\patchabc% Patch \abc
\abc{A}{B}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You can use `regexpatch`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\newcommand{\abc}[2]{#1\ #2}% Magic macro
\newcommand{\patchabc}{%
  \regexpatchcmd{\abc}{\cP.1}{\cP\#2}{}{}%
}
\begin{document}
\abc{A}{B}

\patchabc
\abc{A}{B}
\end{document}
```

The search regular expression `\cP.1` means "find any character of type parameter (that is, category code 6) followed by 1", the replace expression `\cP\#2` means the same, but the character to substitute will be `#`, again with category code 6.

If you want to get rid of `#1` changing it into `#2` wherever it appears in the replacement text of `\abc`, use

```
\regexpatchcmd*{\abc}{\cP.1}{\cP\#2}{}{}
```

However, also an easier `\xpatchcmd` works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\newcommand{\abc}[2]{#1\ #2}% Magic macro
\newcommand{\patchabc}{%
  \xpatchcmd{\abc}{##1}{##2}{}{}%
}
\begin{document}
\abc{A}{B}

\patchabc
\abc{A}{B}
\end{document}
```

Also here you can use `\xpatchcmd*` to change all appearances at once.