# Customization of TOC in KOMA

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

I would like to customize the listing of the chapters given in the table of contents in a `scrbook` document. Given the following example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Alpha}
\chapter{Beta}
\chapter{Gamma}
\end{document}
```

My TOC currently looks like this:

[image: TOC]

How can I customize the text printed in the TOC in the following two regards:

- add a prefix/suffix to the number, e.g. write "Chapter 1" instead of "1"
- increase letter spacing of the chapter title using `microtype`'s `textls`

Comment: You can play with your chapter entry font using `KOMA` with `\setkomafont{chapterentry}{your_font_specification_here}`

Comment: Related: [Adding a string “Chapter” to selected chapter numbers in TOC](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134428/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another suggestion based on the example in [this article](http://www.komascript.de/node/1766) by Markus Kohm at www.komascript.de

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}

\newcommand*{\SavedOriginaladdchaptertocentry}{}
\let\SavedOriginaladdchaptertocentry\addchaptertocentry
\renewcommand*{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{}{% entry without number
    \SavedOriginaladdchaptertocentry{#1}{#2}%
  }{% entry with number
    \SavedOriginaladdchaptertocentry{}{%
      \string\expandafter\string\MakeUppercase\string\chaptername
      ~#1\string\quad\textls[500]{#2}}%
  }%
}%

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Preface}
\chapter{Alpha}
\chapter{Beta}
\chapter{Gamma}
\addchap{Appendix}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have increased the letter spacing to show the effect.

If the letter spacing should be increased for the whole chapterentry you can use

```
\newcommand*{\SavedOriginaladdchaptertocentry}{}
\let\SavedOriginaladdchaptertocentry\addchaptertocentry
\renewcommand*{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{}{% entry without number
    \SavedOriginaladdchaptertocentry{#1}{#2}%
  }{% entry with number
    \SavedOriginaladdchaptertocentry{}{%
      \string\expandafter\string\MakeUppercase\string\chaptername
      ~#1\string\quad{}#2}%
  }%
}%
 \addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\textls[200]}
```

Note that `\textls[200]` have to be the last command for the `chapterentry` font element because it needs an argument

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The command `\textls` works like `\textbf`. So you need the single command `\lsstyle` which is similar to `\bfseries`.

The prefix can be added by the font element `chapterentry`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{microtype}
\addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\lsstyle  Chapter~}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Alpha}
\chapter{Beta}
\chapter{Gamma}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works, but `\addtokomafont` was not intended for this.

Comment: @Manuel: I know. But sometimes you have to expand the meaning ;-)

Comment: I had the same feeling as @Manuel.  How can this be set properly?  Should the OP go for `titletoc` package?

Comment: @Manuel: Are you saying this because the macro involved has the word "font" in it? The alternative is to redefine `\l@chapter` directly, which requires far more obscurity than a user-interface like `\addtokomafont` or `\setkomafont`. I think this is perfectly fine.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Thank you for the hint with `lsstyle`, however, can I also adjust the spacing numerically using `lsstyle`, similary to `textls`? (I only need to add a subtle more spacing there, the `lsstyle` default is too much).

Comment: @Werner I was just pointing it out. There's even a limitation (in some cases\*) in what can go inside it (e.g., `\centering`), so obviously adding `Chapter~` is not recommended.