# Formating single entry on table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

How to format a single entry in the table of contents?

For example, how to add some horizontal space to indent some specific line, including the section number?

ps: I know that I can edit the `toc` file but to do that any time is boring.

Comment: untestet: `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{1cm}}`

Comment: @Johannes_B, it is inserting vertical space. I'd like to format the entry with horizontal space.

Comment: `\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{tester}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\hspace{1cm}\protect\numberline{\thechapter}Text}
\end{document}
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickly defining a new package to keep the preamble clean. You now have the command `\emphchapter` taking a mandatory argument, and an optional for the toc if needed. There is a starred variant as well, setting an unnumbered chapter with indent to the toc. After loading the package, you can use `\setkomafont{emphfont}` or `addtokomafont{emphfont}` to format the toc entry. The indent can be changed by using the usual `setlength` to length `emphindent`.

Patching arguments inside macros can be troublesome, you can use package `etoolbox` and package `regexpatch`. Examples can be found at [Patching arguments inside a macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113147/37907)

Setting the color to blue using `addtokomafont` gives something like this:

[image: sigurTocEmph]

```
\begin{filecontents}{emphchapter.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{emphchapter}[2014/10/29 TeX.SX demo package]
\RequirePackage{regexpatch}
\tracingxpatches
\PassOptionsToPackage{x11names}{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{scrkbase}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\newlength{\emphindent}
\newlength{\starredemphindent}
\setlength{\emphindent}{1cm}
\let\starredemphindent\emphindent
\newkomafont{emphfont}{\normalfont\scshape}


\DeclareDocumentCommand{\numemphfontswitch}{}{\protect\usekomafont{emphfont}\protect\hspace{\emphindent}}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\starredemphfontswitch}{}{\protect\usekomafont{emphfont}\hspace{\starredemphindent}}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\patchchapter}{}{
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}##1}%
}{%
{\numemphfontswitch\protect\numberline{\thechapter}##1}%
}{}{}
\makeatother
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\emphchapter}{ s o m }{
\IfBooleanTF{#1}{
\begingroup
\typeout{starred emphchapter}
\chapter*{#3}
\IfNoValueTF{#2}{
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\starredemphfontswitch#3}
}{
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\starredemphfontswitch#2}
}
\endgroup
}
{
\typeout{numbered emphchapter}
\begingroup
\patchchapter
\IfNoValueTF{#2}{
\chapter{#3}
}{
\chapter[#2]{#3}
}
\endgroup
}
}

\endinput
\end{filecontents}



\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{emphchapter}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\addtokomafont{emphfont}{\color{blue}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{tester}
\blindtext
\emphchapter{emphchapter}
\emphchapter[optional numbered emph]{emphchapter}
\blindtext
\chapter{behind emphchapter}
\blindtext
\chapter{before starred}
\blindtext
\emphchapter*{starred emphchapter}
\blindtext
\emphchapter*[optional starred entry]{starred emphchapter with optional}
\blindtext
\chapter{tester}
\end{document}
```