# Strip environment command in hyperref PDF meta data

Tags: hyperref, environments, metadata

When adding PDF meta data using `hyperref` you can also use certain LaTeX commands which are magically stripped away during the conversion into a PDF string. But this doesn't seem to work with environments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\foo[1]{foo #1}
\newenvironment{fooenv}{foobegin}{fooend}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfauthor=\foo{Author}} % works
\hypersetup{pdftitle={\begin{fooenv}Title\end{fooenv}.}} % error
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Is there any way to make enviroments behave like regular commands in this setting?

Comment: hyperref contains code (in the definition of `\pdfstringdef`), but it is faulty. It uses `#1` instead of `##1`. Make a bug report. (But imho it is not a good idea to use environments there, that's probably the reason nobody ever reported the error.)

Comment: It's not very clear why you'd embed the title in an environment or the author's name in a command to begin with.

Comment: In my opinion, using environments here is as bad as using commands. I just want to end up with something useful in the meta data when arbitrary LaTeX code is copied directly into one of the fields - being aware of the drawbacks. I think that's the overall idea of hyperref allowing LaTeX commands in such places.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Where to report the bug? Is it possible to patch the command using `etoolbox` or something in the short run?

Comment: Write @HeikoOberdiek, and in the short run, I would simply change hyperref.sty and replace the #1 by ##1 in `\def\begin#1{\csname#1\endcsname}%
    \def\end#1{\csname end#1\endcsname}%`

Answer (score 1):

The following workaround allows to use environments as intended by patching the `\pdfstringdef`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\foo[1]{foo #1}
\newenvironment{fooenv}{foobegin}{fooend}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\catcode`\#=12
\newcommand{\patchpdfstringdef}{%
    \patchcmd\pdfstringdef%
        {\def \begin #1{\csname #1\endcsname }}%
        {\def \begin ##1{\csname ##1\endcsname }}%
        {}{}%
    \patchcmd\pdfstringdef%
        {\def \end #1{\csname end#1\endcsname }}%
        {\def \end ##1{\csname end##1\endcsname }}%
        {}{}%

}
\catcode`\#=6
\patchpdfstringdef

\hypersetup{pdfauthor=\foo{Author}} % works
\hypersetup{pdftitle={\begin{fooenv}Title\end{fooenv}.}} % error
\begin{document}
    Hello!
\end{document}
```

It utilizes the answer given in [Patching arguments inside a macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113147/patching-arguments-inside-a-macro).

This results in the following meta data being stored in the PDF (queried by `pdfinfo`):

```
Title:          foobeginTitlefooend.
Author:         foo Author
```