# Reset counter with starred sections as well (example using exsheets)

Tags: numbering, counters, exsheets

I am typesetting exercise/exam sheets with the “exsheets” package. It allows me to reset the question counter with every other counter step (e.g. with every section). Unfortunately this does not work for starred section commands (`\section*{Topic}`), since no counter is stepped with it (see screenshot), but that is the behavior I need.

[image: Screenshot showing the problem.]

Is there a standard solution for that problem? If not, what would be the best/easiest/most elegant/whatever way to implement it?

Comment: This depends on the documentclass, but I'll try to provide a solution.

Comment: This is generally not possible: starred sections don't have a counter that is stepped thus no associated counter is reset. This is not a problem of `exsheets` in particular

Comment: @clemens: Nope, but you could hack into `section*` ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Great! I'm using the KOMA-Script classes.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer probably: `\pretocmd\section{\setcounter{question}{0}}` or something (with `etoolbox`...)

Comment: @clemens: Just doing ... just done it ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose, the question environment has a counter named question, if this is different, change the name.

It's possible to prepend code before `\section` is started either with `\pretocmd` (`etoolbox`) or `\xpretocmd` (`xpatch`) commands. The later works in more sophisticated cases, but `xpatch` calls `etoolbox` anyway.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}


\newcounter{question}[section]

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpretocmd{\section}{\setcounter{question}{0}}{}{} % This does not mean any harm, since it is reset by `\section` anyway, so `\section*` is correct here too.

\begin{document}

\setcounter{question}{5}

\section*{First starred section}

The value of question is now \thequestion



\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed, the counter is named “question” :-)

Comment: The solution works, and I've learned a lot (e.g. the commands `\(x)pretocmd`), thank you! The solution with `\pretocmd` worked as well, can you give some details on the benefits of using “xpatch”?

Comment: @Chris in this case there aren't any benefits, really. But if you want to patch commands defined with `\DeclareRobustCommand` for example it is easier with `xpatch` IIRC

Comment: @clemens: Yes, that's true -- in this case I could restrict to `etoolbox` -- I just use `xpatch` always, since `etoolbox` is loaded anyway then.

Comment: @Chris another example where `xpatch` is easier: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113147/