# Reset counter \section in \part*

Tags: counters, parts, chngcntr

I'm a rookie with LaTeX, I'm using LyX, but I think this is a LaTeX problem.

Im using this LaTeX preamble for reset counter after parts

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{section}{part}
```

But it only works with `\part` and no with `\part*`... I need to have no-numbered parts. What can I do? I don't find anything on the net and my attempts don't work (counterwith, part*...).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: you're right, since `\part*` doesn't step the `part` counter. we need more informations about class used.

Comment: Here's some questions which address similar issues, numbering one counter within starred and unstarred versions of another: [1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71162/reset-section-numbering-between-unnumbered-chapters) [2](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255352/reset-counter-with-starred-sections-as-well-example-using-exsheets) [3](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53529/how-to-reset-footnote-numbering-at-chapter-and-at-frontmatter-chapters)

Comment: Do you *always* use unnumbered parts?

Comment: Thanks all, but Christian answer works like a charm :D.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works for `article.cls` `\parts` since there are no `\chapters` which must be reset too. It's regardless whether `\part` or `\part*` is used, the `\setcounter{section}{0}` just before `\part` does no harm and is done automatically here.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{chngcntr}
%\counterwithin*{section}{part}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpretocmd{\part}{\setcounter{section}{0}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\part*{A part}

\section{A section in part}
\section{Another section in part}

\part*{Another part}

\section{A section in another part}

\section{Another section in another part}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @analca3: It works even without LyX (;-)

Comment: `\setcounter{section}{-1}\stepcounter{section}` is better

Comment: @touhami: Why? I don't suppose that somebody will need a `\label` to the section just before `\part` starts.

Comment: just in case some one start the `part` with `subsection` this help to reset all counters. (by the way for crossreference one need `\refstepcounter`, but you know that)

Comment: @touhami: Yes, `\refstepcounter` -- I was confused for a moment. But since the format updates the underlying counters (`subsection`) are reset even with `setcounter`.