# Trouble with patchcmd and double #

Tags: macros, etoolbox, patching, xpatch

I need to patch the following macro from `gloss-greek.ldf` (`polyglossia`):

```
\def\greek@numbers{%
   \let\latin@alph\@alph%
   \let\latin@Alph\@Alph%
   \if@greek@numerals
      \def\greek@alph##1{\protect\greeknumber{##1}}%
      \def\greek@Alph##1{\protect\Greeknumber{##1}}%
      \let\@alph\greek@alph%
      \let\@Alph\greek@Alph%
   \fi}
```

to the following

```
\def\greek@numbers{%
   \let\latin@alph\@alph%
   \let\latin@Alph\@Alph%
   \if@greek@numerals
      \def\greek@alph##1{\protect\greeknumber{\the##1}}%
      \def\greek@Alph##1{\protect\Greeknumber{\the##1}}%
      \let\@alph\greek@alph%
      \let\@Alph\greek@Alph%
   \fi}
```

(to add the two `\the`s).

However I get problems related to different catcodes of #.

I've tried approaches like the ones mentioned in [Patching arguments inside a macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113147/patching-arguments-inside-a-macro) but I have failed so far.

Working example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\tracingpatches
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\patchme}{%
\xpatchcmd{\greek@numbers}{\greeknumber{##1}}{\greeknumber{\the##1}}{}{} 
\xpatchcmd{\greek@numbers}{\Greeknumber{##1}}{\Greeknumber{\the##1}}{}{}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\patchme
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
a &= b \label{eq:eq1}\\
c &= d \label{eq:eq2}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

This is \eqref{eq:eq2}? Is it really?

\end{document}
```

If the patch were applied the reference would appear correct. Also the log reads:

```
[debug] tracing \patchcmd on input line 28
[debug] analyzing '\greek@numbers'
[debug] ++ control sequence is defined
[debug] ++ control sequence is a macro
[debug] -- nested patching command and parameters in patch
[debug] -> the patching command seems to be nested in the
[debug] argument to some other command
[debug] -> the patch text seems to contain # characters
[debug] -> either avoid nesting or use # characters with
[debug] category code 12 in the patch text
[debug] -> simply doubling the # characters will not work
```

Comment: maybe something like `\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\greek@numbers}{\greeknumber{##1}}{\greeknumber{\the##1}}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\greek@numbers}{\Greeknumber{##1}}{\Greeknumber{\the##1}}{}{}
\makeatother` (note I did not try it))

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes it won't work

Comment: I don't believe in the "different catcodes of #". Show a  complete document that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: You can fix it directly, by avoiding the use of `\xpatchcmd`, and respecifying `\def\greek@numbers` as desired in the preamble.  Is that solution not acceptable?  I suppose your question may be about `xpatch` itself, rather than about the MWE, which can be fixed through other means.

Comment: OK I take it back with the catcodes. If you are trying to patch they will matter. By why are you trying to redefine \@greeknumbers? I see no difference in the output if I do it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `\the` was a work around a bug with `polyglossia` https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/110

Comment: I see. Imho your patch is better then the one suggested in the issue. The expandafter is not necessary, but keeping the \protect leads to a better aux-file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Patching commands with `##` with `etoolbox` (which `xpatch` uses internally) is not possible, as far as I can see.

I'm not sure why you need `\the` in that place, because the output is the same with or without it. Anyway, I'd prefer `\number`.

It is possible to do the patch with `regexpatch`. The patches can be done all at once, noting we want to replace every occurrence of `{##1}` with `{\number##1}`, so we can use `\xpatchcmd*`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{Times New Roman}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd*{\greek@numbers}
  {{##1}}
  {{\number##1}}
  {\typeout{Hurray!}}{\typeout{Rats!}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
a &= b \label{eq:eq1}\\
c &= d \label{eq:eq2}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

This is \eqref{eq:eq2}? Is it really?

\end{document}
```

Here's the relevant part of the terminal output:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-english.ldf)
Hurray!
(./doublehash.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd)
[1] (./doublehash.aux) )
Output written on doublehash.pdf (1 page).
```

Comment: Your MWE gives the improper result, referencing eq 1-alpha', rather than 1-beta'... at least when I compile it.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Timing problems; I removed `\patchme`

Comment: `\the` was about to workaround a bug with `polyglossia` https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/110 The submitter proposes using `\the`. Would you suggest to go with `\number`?

Comment: Regarding the output  at least in my set up (texlive 2015 updated) a get the wrong reference (see also Steven's final example)

Comment: @niels You might use `\greek@numbers` with an explicit number; in this case `\the` would give an error, whereas `\number` wouldn't.

Answer (score 4):

If the problem is about how to fix the MWE, a fix can be had by avoiding the use of `xpatch` altogether, and merely respecifying, in total, the desired definition of `\greek@numbers` in the preamble.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{Times New Roman}

\makeatletter
\def\greek@numbers{%
   \let\latin@alph\@alph%
   \let\latin@Alph\@Alph%
   \if@greek@numerals
      \def\greek@alph##1{\protect\greeknumber{\the##1}}%
      \def\greek@Alph##1{\protect\Greeknumber{\the##1}}%
      \let\@alph\greek@alph%
      \let\@Alph\greek@Alph%
   \fi}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
a &= b \label{eq:eq1}\\
c &= d \label{eq:eq2}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

This is \eqref{eq:eq2}? Is it really?

\end{document}
```

[image]

If however, the real purpose of the OP's question is to understand the nature of why `\xpatchcmd` doesn't like `##1` in its arguments, then this answer sheds no light.

A simpler MWE to demonstrate the problem of `##1` in an `\xpatchcmd` macro is as follows.  If the patch worked, the result would be `Q(C)`, not `B(C)`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\def\A{\def\B##1{B({##1})}}
\xpatchcmd{\A}{B({##1})}{Q({##1})}{\xdef\result{successful}}{\xdef\result{unsuccessful}} 
\A
\begin{document}
\B{C}.  Patch was \result.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You know you just made me feel retard, don't you? ;-)

Comment: Hardly.  The `xpatch` issue is a fascinating question, too.