# Set fixed place for page numbers?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I really tried to reproduce this kind of error with a minimal working example, but whenever I strip it down the error disappears? My problem is, that the place of the page number is not fixed. In the first pages it is ok, e.g. like this:

[image: test1]

Suddenly in my document (no new paragraph change or something like this) it is more down below, so it changes? E.g. see this:

[image: test2]

There is no command or something like this, it just suddenly changes (after page 50) and then it stays there?
So I wanted to ask, if there is a general command with which I can fix the place of the numbers? I tried to set it with `\setlength{\footskip}{5mm}`  which moves the page numbers up, but the problem is, that it is still different, so suddenly it is more down (after page 50).

EDIT:
Here is the setting I use, I do not know which package causes the problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 
        12pt,                               
        bibliography=totoc,     
        index=totoc,    
        abstracton,     
        headsepline,    

        ]{scrreprt}




\usepackage{latexsym}             
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}  

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{subfig}     
\usepackage{float}      
\usepackage{graphicx}       
\usepackage{rotating}  
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{eurosym,bm,amsmath,amssymb,verbatim}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage [round,authoryear] {natbib} Literaturstil
%\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{graphicx,eso-pic,lipsum}
%\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{allwithdot} 
\usepackage[bookmarksopen,hyperfootnotes=false,pdftitle=, pdfauthor=,pdfsubject=Master Thesis]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{listings} 
\lstset{ 
  language=R,            
  basicstyle=\scriptsize,
  showstringspaces=false,
  showspaces=false,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},         
  commentstyle=\color{green},       
  stringstyle=\color{black}
}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{remreset} 
\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{footnote}{chapter}
\makeatother
\usepackage{dblfnote} % multicolumn footnotes
\usepackage{booktabs} % for tables
\KOMAoption{footnotes}{multiple} % multiple footnotes
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{cleveref} % ref to multiple figures
\usepackage{multirow}  % for multirow
\usepackage{bookmark} % for bookmarks

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds} % for quotes


\usepackage{calligra} % for dedication

\usepackage{listings} % for ROutput
```

EDIT: Here is my log-file, I do not know so much about LaTex, so I still do not know what causes this problem? [Link to my log file](http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=xiLrT).

Comment: Without an MWE, figuring what's causing the problem will be difficult. Perhaps the content of your page push the footer down...

Comment: With that amount of footnotes, you're probably using a specific footnote package (with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref). Which is it?

Comment: @Jubobs no, its not the content, since it stays down there, no matter how the content is. The pages before were already "full" of content.

Comment: I added the packages I use.

Comment: Note that you should load [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) later. See [Which packages should be loaded after `hyperref` instead of before?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/5764) and also [Which package should I load first: `hyperref` or `bookmark`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113006/5764)

Comment: Check the log file for warnings.

Comment: @Werner if I load hyperref later I get the message "! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref."

Comment: You say the problem is around page 50 but the log file at the link you give stops after page 4 so isn't much use?

Comment: does the change take place on the first page of a chapter, or in the middle?  if in the middle, you might try processing just that chapter, removing or adding material to get the change to take place on an earlier or later page.  this would help to isolate the point at which the change is triggered, and that should be able to lead you to identify the package or other situation that is the cause.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yeah, because I could not compile it when setting the hyperref package after bookmark.

Comment: I now changed the complete layout of my file and it now works. Unfortunately I don't like it so much, because I had do drop some things. Now it is working but, pah... I think LaTex is even worse than word when using large files, because also the compiling in LaTex takes a very long time and I have to spent hours and hours on small formatting problems which is really annoying!

Comment: @JenBohold: please create an answer for question then to remove it from the list of unanswered questions. Can you do that?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a non reproducible problem that the OP has solved in an unspecified way.