# Problem with \% in PDF bookmark under XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, hyperref, bookmarks

A MWE is:

```
% !TeX program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\section{\^e\%}
\section{20\%}

\end{document}
```

It can work fine under pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. But there is a error under XeLaTeX:

```
(./mwe.out)
Runaway argument?
{ê\BOOKMARK [1][-]{section.2}{20\045}{}
! File ended while scanning use of \@@BOOKMARK.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.5     \begin{document}

? 
(./mwe.out)
Runaway argument?
{ê\BOOKMARK [1][-]{section.2}{20\045}{}
! File ended while scanning use of \@@BOOKMARK.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.5     \begin{document}

? 
\@outlinefile=\write3
\openout3 = `mwe.out'.
```

I can see the bookmark auxiliary file (mwe.out) is

```
\BOOKMARK [1][-]{section.1}{ê%}{}% 1
\BOOKMARK [1][-]{section.2}{20\045}{}% 2
```

I think that it is due to the first `%` in the first `\BOOKMARK`. How can I avoid it under XeLaTeX?

Comment: Seems like a bug. If you load also `bookmark` after `hyperref` it doesn't happen. Loading `bookmark` is indeed recommended.

Answer (score 4):

Load the [`bookmark` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark) instead; it provides an updated bookmarking reference:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\begin{document}

\section{\^e\%}
\section{20\%}

\end{document}
```

`bookmark` loads [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) (see [Which package should I load first: `hyperref` or `bookmark`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113006/5764))

Comment: While it's true that `bookmark` loads `hyperref` because it depends on it, I find it conceptually clearer to explicitly load both.

Comment: @egreg: Agreed and recommended by me. For example, a package such as package `bookmark` might evolve to get rid of the dependency of `hyperref`. An explicit `\usepackage` or `\RequirePackage` can only be dropped, because it is loaded by another package, if the dependency in the other package is part of the *official* interface for this other package.