# Table of contents disappears when I use bookmark or hyperref

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, texstudio, bookmarks

I'm new to latex and I'm trying to write my thesis

I'm having issues with the table of contents. When I call it, normally it works fine and I get entries for my chapters

[image: what I get when I don't use hyperref or bookmark]

but when I add the packages hyperref or bookmark (I uncomment them) the table of contents disappears (I'm left with a black page with just the title "Indice" which is the automatic title that appears on the table of contents page). This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\graphicspath{ {immagini/} }
\textwidth=450pt\oddsidemargin=0pt

\usepackage{cite}
%\usepackage{bookmark}
%\usepackage{Hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        %
        %
        % UNA VOLTA FATTE LE DOVUTE MODIFICHE SOSTITUIRE "RED" CON "BLACK" NEI COMANDI \textcolor
        %
        %
        \begin{center}
            {{\Large{\textsc{Alma Mater Studiorum $\cdot$ Universit\`a di Bologna}}}} 
            \rule[0.1cm]{15.8cm}{0.1mm}
            \rule[0.5cm]{15.8cm}{0.6mm}
            \\\vspace{3mm}
            
            {\small{\bf Scuola di Scienze \\ 
                    Dipartimento di Fisica e Astronomia\\
                    Corso di Laurea in Fisica}}
            
        \end{center}
        
        \vspace{23mm}
        
        \begin{center}{\LARGE{\bf TITOLO TESI}\\
        }\end{center}
        
        \vspace{50mm} \par \noindent
        
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth}
            %
            % INSERIRE IL NOME DEL RELATORE CON IL RELATIVO TITOLO DI DOTTORE O PROFESSORE
            %
            {\large{\bf Relatore: \vspace{2mm}\\\textcolor{black}{
                        Prof./Dott. Nome Cognome}\\\\
                        \textcolor{black}{
                        \bf Correlatore: (eventuale)
                        \vspace{2mm}\\
                        Prof./Dott. Nome Cognome\\\\}}}
        \end{minipage}
        %
        \hfill
        %
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth}\raggedleft \textcolor{black}{
                {\large{\bf Presentata da:
                        \vspace{2mm}\\
                        %
                        % INSERIRE IL NOME DEL CANDIDATO
                        %
                        Nome Cognome}}}
        \end{minipage}
        
        \vspace{40mm}
        
        \begin{center}
            %
            % INSERIRE L'ANNO ACCADEMICO
            %
            Anno Accademico \textcolor{black}{ 2021/2022}
        \end{center}
        
    \end{titlepage}
\chapter*{Abstract}
Abstract goes here

%\chapter*{Dedication}
%To mum and dad

%\chapter*{Declaration}
%I declare that..

%\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
%I want to thank...

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduzione}
\input{capitoli/introduzione}

\chapter{Modello Standard}
\input{capitoli/sm}

\chapter{Analisi Dati}
\input{capitoli/analisiDati}

\chapter{Chapter Four Title}
\input{capitoli/capitolo03}

\chapter{Conclusion}
\input{capitoli/conclusioni}

\appendix
\chapter{Appendice}
\input{capitoli/appendice}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{./biblio}

\end{document}
```

[image: what i get when i use hyperref or bookmark]

I'm using TeXstudio 4.0.4

Thanks in advance

(images are what I get without those packages (1st) and with them (2nd))

EDIT

i forgot, adding these it works fine

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! :) Three hints to improve your code: (1) the example is missing one or more lines at the beginning (it should begin with `\documentclass`), please include them. (2) The `\input` commands are a stumbling block for potential helpers, because we don't have the files "introduzione.tex" etc. and we get an error. It would help if you could remove them, and leave the commands `\chapter`, which are needed to create a TOC. (3) `hyperref` is written in lowercase (not "Hyperref")

Comment: With `\documentclass{book}` I cannot reproduce your error, using *either* pkg `bookmarks` or `hyperref`, or *both*.

Comment: Hi there i don't know how to reply to you but
1) simon, i tried and it didn't work, thanks anyway :)
2) marquinho, \documentclass was present but it copy from my file to this page. Also thanks for your precious advices.

I solved the issue and edited the post. I don't know how to close the thread, maybe a mod can help me. Best regards

(3) simon i tried with your code but it didn't work without the fontenc and inputenc

Comment: Try the code of my answer.

Comment: compile a second time. hyperref will suppress the toc  the first time to avoid errors.

Comment: @gorsedh `hyperref`changes the way the toc is made behind the scenes. And it needs that you compile twice *the same code*. So, just try to run latex twice instead of once. Have also a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113006/which-package-should-i-load-first-hyperref-or-bookmark?rq=1 Possibly it's not needed to load `bookmarks`

Comment: do you know how to close a thread? 
also 
Iacobus1983 thanks for your answer, i tried compiling multiple times but it didn't work before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Answer (score 0):

Open with `sumatra`. See the bookmarks and the colored links in the table of content.

Used

```
\definecolor{mylinks}{rgb}{0.0, 0.28, 0.67} 
    \usepackage[bookmarksnumbered, backref = true]{hyperref}    
    \hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=mylinks,urlcolor=mylinks,citecolor=mylinks}
```

[image]

This is a simplified code (without the `\input`). Must be compiled twice to generate the TOC.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\graphicspath{ {immagini/} }
\textwidth=450pt\oddsidemargin=0pt

\usepackage{cite}

\definecolor{mylinks}{rgb}{0.0, 0.28, 0.67} 
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered, backref = true]{hyperref}    
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=mylinks,urlcolor=mylinks,citecolor=mylinks}

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        %
        %
        % UNA VOLTA FATTE LE DOVUTE MODIFICHE SOSTITUIRE "RED" CON "BLACK" NEI COMANDI \textcolor
        %
        %
        \begin{center}
            {{\Large{\textsc{Alma Mater Studiorum $\cdot$ Universit\`a di Bologna}}}} 
            \rule[0.1cm]{15.8cm}{0.1mm}
            \rule[0.5cm]{15.8cm}{0.6mm}
            \\\vspace{3mm}
            
            {\small{\bf Scuola di Scienze \\ 
                    Dipartimento di Fisica e Astronomia\\
                    Corso di Laurea in Fisica}}
            
        \end{center}
        
        \vspace{23mm}
        
        \begin{center}{\LARGE{\bf TITOLO TESI}\\
        }\end{center}
        
        \vspace{50mm} \par \noindent
        
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth}
            %
            % INSERIRE IL NOME DEL RELATORE CON IL RELATIVO TITOLO DI DOTTORE O PROFESSORE
            %
            {\large{\bf Relatore: \vspace{2mm}\\\textcolor{black}{
                        Prof./Dott. Nome Cognome}\\\\
                    \textcolor{black}{
                        \bf Correlatore: (eventuale)
                        \vspace{2mm}\\
                        Prof./Dott. Nome Cognome\\\\}}}
        \end{minipage}
        %
        \hfill
        %
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth}\raggedleft \textcolor{black}{
                {\large{\bf Presentata da:
                        \vspace{2mm}\\
                        %
                        % INSERIRE IL NOME DEL CANDIDATO
                        %
                        Nome Cognome}}}
        \end{minipage}
        
        \vspace{40mm}
        
        \begin{center}
            %
            % INSERIRE L'ANNO ACCADEMICO
            %
            Anno Accademico \textcolor{black}{ 2021/2022}
        \end{center}
        
    \end{titlepage}
    \chapter*{Abstract}
    Abstract goes here
    
    %\chapter*{Dedication}
    %To mum and dad
    
    %\chapter*{Declaration}
    %I declare that..
    
    %\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
    %I want to thank...
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \chapter{Introduzione}
%   \input{capitoli/introduzione}
    
    \chapter{Modello Standard}
%   \input{capitoli/sm}
    
    \chapter{Analisi Dati}
    \section{Modelli di Fit}
%   \input{capitoli/analisiDati}
    
    \chapter{Chapter Four Title}
%   \input{capitoli/capitolo03}
    
    \chapter{Conclusion}
%   \input{capitoli/conclusioni}
    
    \appendix
    \chapter{Appendice}
%   \input{capitoli/appendice}
%   
%   \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
%   \bibliography{./biblio}
    
\end{document}
```